# How do I use Triple Notch without triggering High Volley

Tags: horizon-forbidden-west

I have two skills from the Hunter tree: Triple Notch and High Volley. The weird thing is that as far as I can tell both are triggered by the same buttons, holding L2 and pressing R1.

Sometimes when I try to add another arrow using Triple Notch I accidentally fire a High Volley. This is quite annoying as I can't really tell right now what the trigger is here for the different behaviour. There must be something beyond the pure button combination I missed that allows me to choose which skill to trigger here.

So how do I trigger these two skills actually, in a way that doesn't cause me to waste arrows by accidentally shooting them into the air?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem too. Since the game doesn’t quite tell you what happen after 2 skills.

I found it. Open weapon wheel. Select the Hunter bow. There is a option to press D pad left or right to select the active skill.

It is very small. Took me a while too.

*Edit*
Added screenshot, with weapon techniques highlighted in pink
[image: Weapon wheel techniques highlighted in pink]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: its in the middle of the wheel

Comment: This was it, and the setting is per bow which explains why it was triggered only some of the time.